# Best Way To Implement Provider in this Notes App

Tags: flutter

I've been learning flutter for sometime now and feel confident with simple constructs i.e. no complex state management stuff. I started reading about 'pragmatic state management' and saw the [Google I/O video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I) talking about Provider and how they at Google themselves are using it as it's much cleaner and easier to use.

Problem : I want to implement this Notes App using Provider, I am not even sure if I am implementing it the correct way. However What I figured out is that the NoteList variable is being updated, anyway that's besides the point.

Code Here : https://github.com/LuD1161/notes_app In  the last commit I show what all I understood about Provider, which  isn't working as you would've guessed ( and hence the mail -_- ). The previous commit is till where the tutorial ended and is working code. Here's the [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVSBUnNUr00) .

#### My app directory structure :

```
lib
├── main.dart
├── models
│   └── note.dart
├── screens
│   ├── note_detail.dart
│   └── note_list.dart
└── utils
    ├── database_helper.dart
    └── NoteProvider.dart
```

#### Info about some of the files here :

`note_detail.dart` : Handles new note insertion `note_list.dart`   : Lists notes saved in the database, on pressing the FAB here you go to the `note_detail` screen, where note gets added.

There's a `updateListView()` function that is run whenever a new note is `saved` or `deleted`.

```
void updateListView() {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
    dbFuture.then((database) {
      Future<List<Note>> noteListFuture = databaseHelper.getNoteList();
      noteListFuture.then((noteList) {
        setState(() {
          this.noteList = noteList;
          this.count = noteList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

`noteList` is a list of notes in the `note_list` screen over which a `ListView.builder` creates a list of.

```
  ListView getnoteListView() {
    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: getPriorityColor(this.noteList[index].priority),
              child: getPriorityIcon(this.noteList[index].priority),
            ),
            title: Text(
              this.noteList[index].title,
              style: titleStyle,
            ),

~~~~ <SNIP> ~~~~
```

I've read a lot of posts and watched quite a few good videos on Provider, however I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. There's some misconception I guess, which the community would better help me understand.

Thanks.

### Update 1

I've changed the `noteListData` in the provider to this ( earlier it was returning a Future ) :

```
List<Note> get noteListData {
    databaseHelper.initializeDatabase().then((dbFuture){
      databaseHelper.getNoteList().then((noteListFuture){
        return noteListFuture;
      });
    });
  }
```

Still I don't see noteList getting populated.

Code in Note List State :

```
class NoteListState extends State<NoteList> {
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  List<Note> noteList;
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final noteProvider = Provider.of<NoteProvider>(context);
    this.noteList = noteProvider.noteListData;             <----- breakpoint here  
    this.count = this.noteList.length;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Note List"),
      ),
```

### Update 2

I changed the code a bit to debug the future calls these and realised this.

```
 List<Note> get noteListData {
    databaseHelper.initializeDatabase().then((dbFuture){
      databaseHelper.getNoteList().then((noteListFuture){
        return noteListFuture;                      <-breakpoint 1
      });
    });
    return [Note("title1", "", 1), Note("title2", "", 1)];<-breakpoint 2
  }
```

In the above code "title1" and "title2" are returned.

From breakpoint 1 - it goes to the async code and gets over nothing is returned.

From breakpoint 2 - this is where data is actually being returned.

Now, I can see the hardcoded results being returned.

### Update 3 - A ray of hope ( working code, but not sure if this's the right way )

Changed the code to set the variable `noteList` of the `NoteProvider` object. This is working but I am a bit unsure if this is the way to go..

```
List<Note> get noteListData {
    databaseHelper.initializeDatabase().then((dbFuture){
      databaseHelper.getNoteList().then((noteListFuture){
        this.noteList = noteListFuture;
      });
    });
    return this.noteList;
  }
```

Can someone suggest how to do it properly or if this is the proper way ?

Comment: If you feel like answering this on reddit : https://www.reddit.com/r/Flutter/comments/fxbfi4/best_way_of_implementing_provider_in_this_notes/

Comment: Please don't encourage people to answer on reddit. Stack Overflow questions and answers should standalone.

Comment: [sometimes, this link may help](https://androidride.com/flutter-notes-taking-app-tutorial/)